# Динамическая разметка xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Друзья, у меня такой вопрос: есть два LinearLayout между которыми расположен ScrollView. При старте я получая высоту экрана устройства и задаю высоту для ScrollView этому размеру, предварительно отнимая ту высоту, которая указана в LinearLayout. В итоге у меня получается шапка вверху, к нижней части прижат LinearLayout с EditText, и, собственно ScrollView для самого контента. И вот когда я, скажем поворачиваю устройство высота всех элементов обновляется, а вот когда выдвигаться сама панель с клавиатурой, шапка уезжает вверх. Как мне ее зафиксировать?

Comment: попробуйте `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` в манифесте для активити указать

Comment: Нет, по прежнему шапка уезжает...